# what is the absolute path to the res/raw folder in your app?

Tags: android, sax

I have an xml file(thexml.xml) and it's related dtd(thedtd.dtd) file in res/raw folder.
this is the DOCTYPE of the xmlfile: `<!DOCTYPE myApp SYSTEM "thedtd.dtd">`
Because the address to the dtd file has been set relatively i get this error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Relative URI "thedtd.dtd"; 
can not be resolved without a base URI.
```

So I am thinking to give the DOCTYPE an absolute path to the dtd file but i don't know what the address is. i tried this

```
android.resource://com.ssh.mine/raw/thedtd
```

note: (com.ssh.mine is the package name of my project)

but it didn't work and i got java.net.MalformedURLException.
so what should the absolute path to the res/raw folder be...

Comment: there are not such thing like absolute path to the resources but you could see ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor/openInputStream methods and how they work with ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE scheme

Answer (score 1):

> what is the absolute path to the res/raw folder in your app?

There is no path. Raw resources are entries in a ZIP archive that is your APK.

> I have an xml file(thexml.xml) and it's related dtd(thedtd.dtd) file in res/raw folder. this is the DOCTYPE of the xmlfile:  Because the address to the dtd file has been set relatively i get this error:

You may have better luck using `assets/` rather than `res/raw/`, though depending on what you are using to consume the XML, I suspect that neither will work. Worst-case scenario, you will need to copy the files to internal storage (e.g., `getFilesDir()`) and then use them.

Or, put the XML in `res/xml/` and get rid of the DTD, in which case you can get an `XmlPullParser` on the XML from the `Resources` object.

Answer (score 0):

Resources are a part of the APK file.  There is no way to refer to a segment of the APK with a URI.

Instead, you should intercept your parser's call to locate the DTD.  Presuming you are using the built-in Android parser, have a look at the docs for [EntityResolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/EntityResolver.html)